# What would you call the paper you work out your math on?

Tags: word-request

Without computers, we would need to work out difficult math problems on paper. This is still true in math tests, where the teacher would give students a few pieces of paper so they can work out their problems. Usually, students can ask for more paper, if needed.

I don't know a specific word for this kind of paper. I was guessing that it might be *working paper* or *jotting paper*, but they don't sound quite right.

What should I call this kind of paper in English?

Comment: I don't think there is any specific word for such kind of paper or if there is any I might not be aware of it. However I have often informally used "*rough paper*". Get it, paper for rough work - rough paper.!!

Comment: Rough work is done on **scrap paper**. See example sentence on page of [this document](http://www.southessex.ac.uk/sites/default/files/downloads/HE%20Exam%20Guide%20for%20Students.doc).

Comment: @Laure: I'm showing my age. In my youth "scrap paper" meant paper to be "scrapped" or discarded; and because our parents and teachers, from whom we learned the term, had been through WWII, when the government made great efforts to reuse strategic materials, there was a strong sense of "paper-to-be-scrapped-and-recycled".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The usual term when I was in school was *scratch paper*—scraps of paper you "scratch out" calculations and notes on, to be discarded after results have been fair-copied into your exam answer or essay.

- Laure calls my attention to *scrap paper*, which appears from [this GoogleNGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scrap+paper%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cscratch+paper%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cscrap+paper%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cscratch+paper%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cscrap%20paper%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscratch%20paper%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscrap%20paper%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscratch%20paper%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0) almost always to have been more  popular in BrE, and to have become more popular in AmE since I left high school.

[image]

- Jim calls my attention to the alternative term *work sheet*. This works, too; but in my experience it is usually employed when you are supposed to turn in the paper, with your exam, rather than discarding it.

A *working paper* is usually either a) a report on a "work-in-progress" or b) a "working" version of a paper which is still in development and not yet ready for submission or publication.

The traditional term in textual criticism for an author's manuscript draft, often full of strikethroughs, insertions and corrections, is *foul papers*, from which a "clean" version or *fair copy* is made.

Comment: +1  You might also talk about *worksheets* and how that term may or may not be applicable.

Comment: This is simpler that I thought, perhaps the word *scratch paper* might have crossed my eyes, but I couldn't recall it when I need to use it. Silly me. Big thanks for two new words for me (*foul papers* and *fair copy*), and a nice tip on *working paper* usages. Thank you.

Comment: In the UK I've heard *scrap* paper more often than *scratch* paper.

Comment: @Laure: I'm showing my age. In my youth "scrap paper" meant paper to be "scrapped" or discarded; and because our parents and teachers, from whom we learned the term, had been through WWII, when the government made great efforts to reuse strategic materials, there was a strong sense of "paper-to-be-scrapped-and-recycled".

Comment: And you don't think it's more of a US/UK difference, rather than a generation difference?

Comment: @Laure: It appears from [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scrap+paper%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cscratch+paper%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cscrap+paper%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cscratch+paper%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cscrap%20paper%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscratch%20paper%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscrap%20paper%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscratch%20paper%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0) to be both. I note that the crossover in AmE is 1966, the year after I started college.

Comment: Dammit! I wanted to follow a link to that NGram! Partly because I always forget how to force the corpus *within the search term*, but mainly because I just wanted to see how ***rough paper*** played out on that chart.

Comment: @StoneyB: In my youth we didn't have *toilet **tissue***, and I always hated the ['Bronco' shiny paper](http://www.sciencemuseum.org.uk/broughttolife/objects/display.aspx?id=1790) that we had a huge cupboard full of. Which I've only just discovered through that link, was apparently discontinued in 1950 (a few years before I was born). I suppose we had so much of it because we were poor, and nobody else liked it either, so my parents probably got a job lot of unwanted/unsaleable stock. When we finally got it, I thought toilet tissue was the best thing since sliced bread (wiped *much* better! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Gosh, I remember the shock of encountering that stuff (not Bronco, specifically, but smooth paper) when my family went to England in '54. Nothing--not the dialect, not the cars, not the stores, not the schools--was so alien as that.

Comment: The term [_scrap paper_](https://www.google.com/#q=%22scrap+paper%22&tbm=shop) is often used by crafters and artisans, so this Ngram may not be accurate for comparison purposes.

Answer (score 4):

In exams at school, we always called it "rough paper", meaning paper that was used only for working out calculations etc. and to be thrown away afterwards. We could also have called it "scrap paper".

I have not heard the term "scratch paper" as suggested by the other answerer and whilst I could understand it from context, it would not be a familiar term to me. It sounds more like a phrase used by the older generations, like something my parents might say (I'm 27.) Then again, it could be an area thing, too. I am from the UK.

Comment: +1 Interesting. Although I've never encountered "rough paper" in this sense, quick sketches intended for future elaboration are very often called "roughs" over here, and hasty first versions of texts are "rough drafts". GoogleBooks provides a handful of collocations of "rough paper" with "exam" in the GB corpus, though far fewer than "scrap paper" and "exam".

Comment: We had "rough books" as well at school which were a type of exercise book that we used specifically for rough working.

Comment: I wonder how much of the language we use is "scholiolect", the forms in use in the particular school we happened to attend.

Comment: @StoneyB: starsplusplus doesn't provide "location" on his/her profile, but perhaps it's ***UK**?* I think I recall using "rough paper" at school 50 years ago, and I'm certain my daughter had it less than 10 years ago. I remember her complaining that *my* "scrap paper" (boxes of by-then-unwanted continuous listing paper) wasn't as good as the stuff she used at school. Which was called *rough paper* because it was for rough working (sums, outline notes, preliminary sketches, etc). But as a budding artist at the time, she liked the way it took crayon/charcoal, in the literal sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, starsplusplus says "I am from the UK" at the end of the post. Interestingly, most GoogleBooks hits on "rough paper" address its use by artists, not its use on exams. [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rough+paper%2Cscrap+paper&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crough%20paper%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscrap%20paper%3B%2Cc0) suggests BrE "rough paper" has been essentially flat since 1900, while "scrap paper" has been rising since the '20s, passing "rough" in about the year I finished high school.

Comment: *Rough* and *scrap paper* from me too. I have never come across "scratch paper".

Comment: The [evidence from NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scratch+paper%2Crough+paper%2Cscrap+paper&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cscratch%20paper%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crough%20paper%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscrap%20paper%3B%2Cc0) strongly suggests that *scratch paper* is a more recent US alternative to (now mainly UK-based) *rough paper*. But there's no easy way to determine how often *scrap paper* is actually used in that way, as opposed to being pulped and recycled.

Comment: I am from the U.S. and have always used 'scratch paper' and had never heard of 'rough paper', so my feeling is that these two are terms related to location of the speaker; i.e. scratch paper=U.S. and rough paper=U.K.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst working at my computer, I often have a 'scribble pad' beside me, to work things out on, or to jot down unfinished ideas